# Adding options into array CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have another problem. I have to tables: 1 - with users 2 - with groups. Tables are connected with id of groups - groupid from table 1 is connected with id of group from table 2.

I wanted to create list of options using this code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Priority', array(
'label' => 'Group', 
'options' => $groups_array
));
```

Now the $group_array should look

`like array('1' => 'Admin', '2' => 'User');`

I've tried to push group id and group name via this code, but it doesn't work properly (it adds group with ID lowered by 1 - i assume that the ID isn't id of group but ID of name position in array $group_array.

```
$groups_array = array();

foreach($groups as $group):

echo $group['Group']['ID']; echo $group['Group']['Name'];

array_push($groups_array, $group['Group']['ID']=$group['Group']['Name']);

endforeach;
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `array_push()`, since you intend to set the array index directly from `$group['Group']['ID']`, use that value as the index to `$groups_array` in the assignment:

```
$groups_array = array();
foreach ($groups as $group) {
  // assign a new key $group['Group']['ID'] directly
  $groups_array[$group['Group']['ID']] = $group['Group']['Name'];
}
```

#### Here's what went wrong:

The "reduced by one" issue you describe was sort of a coincidence of having users with ids `1, 2` appending to an array. The first was appended at index `0` and the second as `1`. If the array started non-empty, the users would have been appended to the end of it.

When you did

```
array_push($groups_array, $group['Group']['ID']=$group['Group']['Name']);
```

...PHP managed to assign the `Name` key into the existing `ID` key, overwriting the `ID` with the name, and then *return* that value into the second parameter of `array_push()`. So really what PHP eventually saw was

```
array_push($groups_array, 'Admin');
array_push($groups_array, 'User');
```

Comment: You are awesome :o Thanks for solving my problem :) Have a nice day!